# Django avoid creating testing database for exsting one

Tags: django

I have an existing database "**A**" with data loaded, that is part of a different project that I'm integrating with. I'm using multi database Django support and storing the stuff I need to persist in my database "**B**" which is Django modeled.

Now I would like to run tests, which creates me two test databases. The problem is that test database "A" has no tables or data.

Is there a way to avoid creating a test database for "**A**" (which is a read-only non production database) and directly use "**A**"?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading `django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner.setup_databases` correctly, you can avoid creating a test database by defining a `'TEST_MIRROR'` setting for your database.

The option is intended to be used for [testing master/slave configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#topics-testing-masterslave), but you can achieve the intended effect if you set the mirror to be the same database as the one you are configuring the option on:

```
DATABASES = { 
    'A': {
        'ENGINE': ..., # standard configuration goes here
        'TEST_MIRROR': 'A',
    }, 
    'B': {
        'ENGINE': ..., # no TEST_MIRROR, a test database will be created for B
    } 
}
```

No test database will be created for "**A**", it will instead be replaced by its `TEST_MIRROR`, which is also "**A**", so the tests will run on "**A**" and "**test_B**" as intended.

Comment: I don't know if it's been fixed in newer versions (Django 1.4.8 here), but the test runner still tries to flush `A`, wiping out all the data.